# which dll's are used by an episerver project?

Tags: setup-project, gac, episerver

An episerver installation puts the episerver assemblies in the GAC, I see them with C:/windows/assembly.

Besides, all the episerver dll's are present in C:/Program files/Episerver after an episerver installation.

When a create an episerver project via the episerver deployment center or with Visual Studio 2010 using the episerver template, I see that the bin-folder of the newly created project contains a lot of episerver-dlls, which is not very surprising. And I suppose that they are copied from C:/Program files/. If I open the project in visual studio, I see that it's those dll's that are referenced and not the ones from the GAC or from C:/program files/episerver.

Well, all of this is very confusing.
Why is Episerver putting dll's in the gac and not referencing them? What is the best way to handle references to episerver dll's for development in a team?

Moreover, IF episerver would reference the ddl's from the GAC, how would I see that in VS. I mean, what would the properties of the reference be?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is all just episerver deployments decisions. I'll try and go over every your question one by one:

1. Putting dlls into GAC is useful when you want your users to access dlls in the reference dialog from ".NET Framework" tab. Suppose you're creating simple project (not episerver one) and want to add episerver dlls. Instead of looking for them on the hard drive you reference ones that are pointed from the GAC. That's easy for development.
2. Why not reference GAC dlls ? It's to easier deploy your solution with the dlls. Suppose you're deploying your solution to the server. Server won't be having episerver dlls in the GAC (and shouldn't have, anyway). So they're probably setting "copy local = true" property to copy the dlls into the output folder, making your solution portable. Also, the GAC assemblies aren't "referenced" - GAC just contains copies in a case of need and a reference is added to the "program files" folder with the dlls.
3. Best way for a development team is to use GAC or to define some kind of "Third Party"("externals") folder in the repository and put your dlls there (and reference from there). First approach requires episerver install on every dev machine, second uses up some space in your repository.
4. As GAC assemblies can't be referenced (they actually can be, but it's a headache), there is virtually no difference between the result - different paths only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but points 1 and 4 seem contradictory for me. Besides, in VS I don't see the episerver dll's on the .NET tab, so probably point 4 is the correct statement. And point 3 seems also to contradict with point 4, or?

Comment: Regarding point 2: Episerver seems to require an episerver installation on the production server, because in the episerver.config there are references like physicalPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS. That's because the files of the CMS are not under the webroot, but are there on a central location. This seems not very clean to me, but I understand that it has it's advantages.

Comment: It was probably my poor writing :) Pp. 1 and 4 - yeah, it was my mistake - GAC'ed assemblies don't get on to the .net tab. Pp.3 and 4 - have no relation whatsoever. When I said "use GAC" in p.3, I meant use an episerver install (which puts libraries to GAC). GAC is good for purposes of deployment/usage - you don't have to include .dll files in the output folder, .NET will find references in GAC.

Answer (score 2):

We usually create a separate directory where we store all .dll-files and reference them from that directory. This means all third party-librarys and episerver-dlls.
The biggest reason for doing this is to avoid a hassle when a new developer needs to setup the project, and also to avoid conflicts between different versions when referencing from GAC.